# EE module dependencies vs. Build path project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a problem:

I have an EJB project which is EE-module-dependant of a JavaProject.
My EJB project has classes that won't compile because of missing types (which are present in the JavaProject). The project won't compile unless I refresh/open-close the project/ clean-build etc. Eventually, it does compile.

My question is how do I get around this problem. Is it a good idea to define the JavaProject in the build path as well as in the EE module dependencies of this EJB project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having to refresh the project before things build, then something is modifying project files outside of Eclipse. Are you using Ant or Maven or any other command line tools to operate on these projects?

Duplicating your dependency specification will not resolve this issue.